# Django1.8 and Python 2.7: Radio button stores the first option whatever is my choice

Tags: python, django, forms, http-post

I'm using Django 1.8 and python 2.7

In my template I have a radio button.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="radios">Liquids:</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="radio-inline" for="radios">
                    <input type="radio" name="liquids" id="liquids" value="1" disabled>
                    With cough
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline" for="radios">
                    <input type="radio" name="liquids" id="liquids" value="0" >
                    No cough
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I push the `submit` button whatever is my choice, the first option is taken as selected. Do you know how to fix this?

How do I get the correct value of radio choice in `views.py`?

Also, when I render the template having filled values with selected the 2nd option, the radio button for the first option is selected in template.

Comment: How are you using this in the view?

Comment: Use the developer tools of your browser to see what is actually on the page, and what is sent to Django. The problem is probably entirely outside Django, just in the HTML.

Comment: Also you have two things with the same id ("liquids"), that's illegal HTML (but won't cause this problem).

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added my `views.py`.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich How can I do it?

Comment: That code is unreadable, sorry. Where exactly is it showing the radio button selection? And why aren't you using the Django forms framework?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes you are right. Please ignore my `views.py`. 
How do I get the correct value of radio choice in `views.py` regarding my template html code?

Comment: I'd recommend not rendering your inputs manually but using a library such as django-bootstrap3 to render the forms.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide your complete HTML page? Probably you forgot to use `<form></form>` HTML tag.

When you need to get the selected values of an input element you can use jQuery. The function `.serializeArray();` will come in handy.

`var fields = $( ":input" ).serializeArray();`

Comment: <form></form> tags are included in my template. How do I use/control radio buttons having different IDs in views?

Comment: What do you need to control?

Comment: I need to get the selected radio value and add it to a json string. And next use this value to render the same template having this radio button value checked.